# Обработка клика на псевдоэлемент JS(JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!

Помогите решить задачу.

В моем примере есть 4 квадрата, красные это псевдоэлементы. Мне нужно обрабатывать клик по всем псевдоэлементам (красным квадратам).

Вот мое решение, но в этом решении проблема в том, что я могу обработать
клик только по **одному элементу**, а мне нужно **по двум.** Класс менять нельзя =(

Я пытался:

- Помещал квадраты в один общий блок с классом `inner` и далее в переменной `.inner > *`
- Использование `getElementbyClass`, `querySelectorAll` - не дало нужного результата

Заранее спасибо!

```js
let i = 0;
let block = document.querySelector('.block');

$(block).on('click', function(e){
    if (e.offsetX > block.offsetWidth) {
        i++;
    } else {
        return;
    }
  console.log(i);
});
```

```css
.block {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 75px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <div class="block"></div>  
 <br>
 <div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Покажите пример, как вы делали с `querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let i = 0;
let block = document.querySelector('.block');

$('.block').on('click', function(e){
    if (e.offsetX > block.offsetWidth) {
        i++;
    } else {
        return;
    }
  console.log(i);
});
```

чутка переписал ваш код